# Facebook Lead Ads API - Retrieve Information (Age Group and etc)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I saw in the Facebook API that I can retrieve the Bulk Data, but this doesn't **return** information about the **Lead Ad**. I am interested in retrieving what type of user I am targeting so I can have for reference and statistics. **Fields like Age Range, Country and etc**. The problem is that I am going to run a couple of them at the same time targeting different age groups and countries.

```
response:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_time": "2018-02-28T08:49:14+0000", 
      "id": "<LEAD_ID>", 
      "ad_id": "<AD_ID>",
      "form_id": "<FORM_ID>",
      "field_data": [
        {
          "name": "car_make",
          "values": [
            "Honda"
          ]
        }, 
        {
          "name": "full_name", 
          "values": [
            "Joe Example"
          ]
        }, 
        {
          "name": "email", 
          "values": [
            "joe@example.com"
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "OTc2Nz3M8MTgyMzU1NDMy", 
      "after": "OTcxNjcyOTg8ANTI4NzE4"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not provide details about individuals that have completed your lead forms, but does provide aggregated information via the [Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.9), including [breakdowns by age and gender](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/breakdowns/v2.9).